# Connect to remote mysql via terminal

Tags: mysql, connection

For a test I set up user mysql user with % access.  When I try to connect from a remote machine I get:

Enter password:

Then immediately get this:

**ERROR 2003 (HY000):  Can’t connect to MySQL server on ‘xxxxxxx’ (1)**

Any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to comment the `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in your **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
# security:
# using "localhost" in connects uses sockets by default
# skip-networking
# bind-address = 127.0.0.1  --- commented
```

and watch the results. If not work try to use the IP address and if still not work. roll back the original file.

Answer (score 19):

Verify that you can connect to the mysql port with telnet from that remote machine, e.g.

```
telnet 192.168.1.52 3306
```

If that fails, there's a firewall somewhere preventing you to connect, or you're running mysql on a different port than the default(3306) or mysql isn't configured to listen on the interface/ip address (maybe it's just configured to listen on  connections from localhost, check the `bind-address` configuration in the my.cnf config file)

Comment: tried commenting out bind.  can't telnet, must be a firewall issue, it's on 3306.   thanks though

Comment: Does a blank telnet screen count as success for this? Or should I see some output?

Comment: @Marvin That's because you're trying to run this command somewhere you are not supposed to run it. You need to run this in either a linux shell, an OSX shell or a windows command terminal. - or it's because you've typed something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @nos Never mind that, I figured out that the Telnet Client was not being used and I had to enable it in settings (I found this from another SO question). Now it is giving me lots of weird characters.

Comment: This is what it shows: ```5.6.39-cll-lveΘkDE4us`faÇsq][3+|TmId:mysql_native_password```

Comment: Seems reasonable. You got a response from MySQL, so you can conclude that there is no firewall blocking access.

Answer (score 3):

Can you telnet to the MySQL port 3306? If you can't then check to make sure the MySQL server service is listening on that port. Open a command prompt and type the following example.
Example: telnet yourmysqlservername.com 3306